# How to return lowest value in a filtered list greater than zero

Tags: excel-formula

I need help creating a formula in excel 2016 that will show me the lowest/smallest value in a filtered list that is greater than zero.  There may be duplicates.  For example:

Lowest value: should be 1.5

```
1.5
0.0
1.8
2.9
1.2 (hidden/filtered out)
1.5
3.4
1.3 (hidden/filtered out)
0.0 (hidden/filtered out)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use this array formula:

```
=MIN(IF((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B10,ROW(B2:B10)-MIN(ROW(B2:B10)),,1)))*(B2:B10>0),B2:B10))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode:

[image]

But ultimately you can filter your data one more step by including the >0 in the filter and then a simple SUBTOTAL will work:

```
=SUBTOTAL(5,B2:B10)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jd935610 please consider marking correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.